# Java analogue of C# Dictionary with IEqualityComparer(TKey)

Tags: c#, java, dictionary, comparator

Is there a Map-based class in Java (in lang, apache commons or somewhere else) which has possibility to provide custom key equality comparer?

In C# it is possible with Dictionary class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which you can [construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29) with a custom [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: They're not equivalent. Dictionary is hash based and close to O(1) where as TreeMap uses comparisons and is O(n).